# System of linear equations in C

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Find all solutions for [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3Cu.png) depending on the parametres a,b ∈ C...

With the usage of elementary row operations we can get to the reduced [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZUt7.png)
Now, what is the appropriate way of the parametrical solution and how do parametres a,b affect our solutions (existece, values, # of solutions...)?

Comment: What variables do you have besides a and b? Maybe it is better to list the original set of equations?

Answer (score -1):

thought it was obvious from the first matrix.. the columns represent variables x1, x2, x3 plus we have the parameters a, b.
The system would look like this:

1. -ix1 + ax2 + (2-4i)x3 = 0
2. x1 + 2ix2 + bx3 = 0
3. ix1 - x2 + ix3 = 1

Comment: Don't use the answers as places for discussion.